# setPeopleIds() is not working with WEB shareDialog()

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to tag friends into my post. Facebook docs says that I need to use setPeopleIds() method in my ShareDialogBuilder.
Here is my code:

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=ssl"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(image.getUrl()))
                .setContentTitle("Some title")
                .setContentDescription("Some desc")
                .setPeopleIds(ids)
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

But code above working only for NATIVE mode. In WEB mode code not works.
Can you tell me please: is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?